# Angular: how to cast FormGroup.value to Map?

Tags: angular, dictionary, formgroups

I have a FormGroup which has a few FormControls, each one using a string as the name and an object (Answer) as the value.

What I was trying is to cast the value of the formgroup directly to a Map but it turns out to be undefined.

e.g.

```
const formDataMap: Map<string, Answer> = this.form.value as Map<string, Answer>;
```

The only way to get this is as follows:

```
const formDataMap: Map<String, Answer> = new Map<String, Answer>(); 

Object.keys(formData).forEach((key) => { 
    formDataMap.set(key, formData[key] as Answer); 
});
```

Shouldn't this be the natural cast, from a form to a Map?

Answer (score 1):

The `as` operator from typescript only defines the type of that property. It does not push items to your map. So you will need to loop through the properties and push them to your map manually like you have done.

Comment: Ok, so no way to get this automatically. If so then, what's the data-structure behind the scenes used to store the (key, value) pairs of the form? I read about an array of arrays, but what's the correct type declaration?

Comment: @JohnBlack are you asking about the type declaration of the Map or of the FormGroup (where your formData is stored in your component)

Comment: I mean the type of form.value

Comment: @JohnBlack If you console.log form.value you can see it is just an object `{key: value}`, so the type would be something like `{[key: string]: any}`